# ¿Cómo acceder localmente a un dashboard creado con flexdashboar en R?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdasboard

He creado un dashboard con flexdashboar, pero deseo que accedan al dashboard localmente. Es decir, compartir una url local y que otro usuario pueda acceder. En palabras sencillas que mi pc sea el servidor.

Buscando en la web encontré que corriendo el siguiente codigo.

```
rmarkdown::run("miapp.Rmd", shiny_args = list(port = 3838, host = "0.0.0.0"))
```

Y que accediendo a la url

```
http://localhost:3838
```

Puedes acceder. Pero no sirve, entonces mi consulta es ¿Puedo compartir mi dashboard localmente? ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: En teoría lo que tienes al ejecutar una app shiny es un miniservidor web, al que accedes normalmente desde tu mismo equipo, pero si la red interna no tiene ninguna restricción no veo por que no podría  un colega tuyo acceder a la app invocando `http://<tu ip local>` o incluso `http://<nombre de tu pc>`

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, Entonces debo de tener un problema en la red interna.

Comment: Prueba con algún port más común tipo el 80 o el 8080, eso tal vez ayude.